# I want to display mulitple outputs in a single dialog box. How do I accomplish this?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jdialog

I want the user to enter the various strings and integers in dialog boxes, but then I want the final output with all the information to be displayed in one dialog box. This is what I have:

```
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Product Name" + inv[i].getName(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Product Type" + theItem.getType(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Product Number", + theItem.getpNumber(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Amount of Units in Stock", + theItem.getUnits(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Price per Unit", + theItem.getPrice(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Total cost for %s in stock: $%.2f", theItem.getName(), theItem.calculateTotalPrice(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: As an aside, I cannot see how that snippet could compile, let alone run.

Answer (score 1):

There are various options.

1. Put the ouput in a JTextArea that
   is used as the component for
   showMessageDialog.
2. Use HTML
   formatting on the strings - JLabel
   (default component for rendering
   Strings in a JOptionPane) will
   render simple HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make your own dialog class, by extending `JDialog` and customizing it appropriately.